# Implementing polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I was watching [Google talk on polymorphism and clean code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&index=6&list=PLGvfHSgImk4YXkVse1MlfaqMgIcFybgN2).

In that, the speaker was explaining how to create a clean code for an operation like 1+2*3:

[image]

```
class Node{
    virtual double evaluate() = 0;
};
class ValueNode :Node{
    double value;
    double evaluate(){
        return value;
    }
};
class OpNode :Node{
    Node left;
    Node right;
    virtual double evaluate() = 0;
};
class AdditionNode : OpNode{
    double evaluate(){
        return left.evaluate() + right.evaluate();
    }
};
class MultiplyNode : OpNode{
    double evaluate(){
        return left.evaluate() * right.evaluate();
    }
};
```

I just copied the speaker's java code in c++. But in c++

```
Node left;
Node right;
```

will mean that left and right are objects of Node which is an abstract class and hence not allowed.

> How do I fix this.

---

Edit: I modified the code based on suggestions given by @Remy Lebeau. I expected the output to be 7, but I am getting 687194771 instead.

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual int evaluate() = 0;
}; 

class ValueNode : public Node {
public:
    int value;
    int evaluate() {
        return value;
    }
}; 

class OpNode : public Node {
public:
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
}; 

class AdditionNode : public OpNode {
public:
    int evaluate() {
        return left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
    }
}; 

class MultiplyNode : public OpNode {
public:
    int evaluate() {
        return left->evaluate() * right->evaluate();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ValueNode value1;
    value1.value = 1;

    ValueNode value2;
    value1.value = 2;

    ValueNode value3;
    value1.value = 3;

    MultiplyNode multiply;
    multiply.left = &value2;
    multiply.right = &value3;

    AdditionNode add;
    add.left = &value1;
    add.right = &multiply;

    int result = add.evaluate();
    cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Where is my error?

Comment: class ValueNode and class AdditionNode use prefix virtual before evaluate() declarations.

Comment: maybe use `Node*` (or smart pointers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism only works when you use pointers/references to objects.  In Java, class objects are always allocated dynamically and referred to by pointer.  So, in C++, the class declarations would need to look like this:

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual double evaluate() = 0;
};

class ValueNode : public Node {
public:
    double value;
    double evaluate() {
        return value;
    }
};

class OpNode : public Node {
public:
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

class AdditionNode : public OpNode {
public:
    double evaluate() {
        return left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
    }
};

class MultiplyNode : public OpNode {
public:
    double evaluate() {
        return left->evaluate() * right->evaluate();
    }
};
```

And then you can set up the example expression `1+(2*3)` like this:

```
ValueNode value1;
value1.value = 1;

ValueNode value2;
value2.value = 2;

ValueNode value3;
value3.value = 3;

MultiplyNode multiply;
multiply.left = &value2;
multiply.right = &value3;

AdditionNode add;
add.left = &value1;
add.right = &multiply;

double result = add.evaluate();
```

When `add.evaluate()` is called, it returns the sum of the values returned by calling `left->evaluate()` and `right->evaluate()`, where `left` is pointing at `value1` and `right` is pointing at `multiply`.

When `value1->evaluate()` is called, it returns its `value` field, which is `1`.

When `multiply->evaluate()` is called, it returns the product of the values returned by calling `left->evaluate()` and `right->evaluate()`, where `left` is pointing at `value2` and `right` is pointing at `value3`.

When `value2->evaluate()` is called, it returns its `value` field, which is `2`.

When `value3->evaluate()` is called, it returns its `value` field, which is `3`.

Thus, `add.evaluate()` returns the sum of `1` plus `2*3`, which is `7`.

Comment: The nodes left and right are storing memory addresses here. How do they evaluate to values in the operation on the fly?

Comment: @roang: That's what `->` does; when you use `x.y()` to call a method, `x` must be a raw value or act like one (e.g. a C++ seamless reference type declared with `typename& x`), when you use `x->y()`, `x` is a pointer (or pointer-like thing, e.g. an iterator) that gets dereferenced to find and call `y`.

Comment: @roang: When calling `left->evaluate()` or `right->evaluate()`, the compiler dereferences the pointer to reach the actual `Node` object, and then calls `evaluate()` on it.  Since `evaluate()` is virtual, the call gets dispatched to the most-derived implementation, whether that be `ValueNode::evaluate()`, `MultiplyNode::evaluate()`, or `AdditionNode::evaluate()`, depending on what type of object the pointer is pointing at.  If you really want to know the specific details about how polymorphic methods are dispatched, you should get a good C++ book that explains how virtual method tables work.

Comment: @roang: the `->` operator is the same as the `*` and `.` operators working together, eg calling `left->evaluate()` is the same thing as calling `(*left).evaluate()`.

Comment: But when I changed the double to int and ran this code I am getting result as 687194771. Please excuse my lack of understanding.

Comment: @roang: changed where exactly?  You need to be more specific.  The code I have shown works fine for both `int` and `double` values (or, for that matter, any types that implement compatible `+` and `*` binary operators).  If you have a piece of code that is not working the way you are expecting, then please edit your question to provide those details.

Comment: @roang: you are initializing `value1.value` 3 times and not initializing `value2.value` or `value3.value` at all, so they have random values.  That was a typo in my initial answer that I fixed in a later edit, but you apparently didn't pick up on it.  And FYI, when you edit a question, don't wipe out the details of the original question, just append new details as needed.  I fixed your edit.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this.

Use `Node*` instead of `Node`.

```
class OpNode : public Node{
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    // There is no need to redeclare a pure virtual function.
    // virtual double evaluate() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make left and right *pointers*:

```
Node* left;
Node* right;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy Java code into equivalent C++ syntax, and expect it to work.

C++ objects work in a completely different way than Java objects. You cannot compare C++ objects to Java objects. They are fundamentally different.

The C++ equivalent to Java's objects would be reference-counted objects, like `std::shared_ptr`, so the equivalent C++ pseudo-code (imitating your style) would be:

```
class OpNode :Node{
    std::shared_ptr<Node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> right;
    virtual double evaluate() = 0;
};
```

With a typical subclass being:

```
class AdditionNode : OpNode{
    double evaluate(){
        return left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
    }
};
```

I'm leaving out the same details you left out, such as private/public access classes, etc...

Comment: Is it right to use left->evaluate() + right->evaluate();
Since left and right are of type Node which is an abstract class?

Comment: It is as right as invoking any other virtual method in an abstract class.

Comment: @roang: `evaluate()` is a virtual method.  When you call a virtual method using a pointer/reference to a base class (regardless of whether the base class is abstract or not), the call gets dispatched to the object's most-derived implementation of that method.  So, when you call `evaluate()` on a `Node*` pointer, you will actually be calling `ValueNode::evaluate()`, `MultiplyNode::evaluate()`, or `AdditionNode::evaluate()`, depending on what type of derived object the `Node*` pointer is actually pointing at.